# Avoiding explicit looping in applying a complex function to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, performance, loops, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to loop over a np.array with a non-trivial function, taking the n element of the array and some other parameters. Yet I have noticed that so far the most performing way is to use list comprehension, is there any other faster way to perform this? the "map" function does not seem to be any faster and I can not believe that explicit looping is the fastest way... 
Below some test code and toy data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from functools import partial

input_data = np.array([[207843.5, 468331.5],
       [209827.5, 469081.5],
       [209572.5, 468870.5],
       [209327.5, 468720.5],
       [207722.5, 468209.5]])

coordinates = np.array([
       [194072.430, 440034.24      ],
        [194172.74      , 440054.48      ],
       [209828.5, 469083.5],
       [194166.670, 440062.43      ],
       [194163.64      , 440066.4       ],
       [209327.5, 468720.5],
       [194145.431, 440090.24      ],
       [194195.43, 440092.24      ]])

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1,
                        algorithm='ball_tree', leaf_size = 15).fit(coordinates)


def fun(measure,
        nbrs,
        coordinates
                ):
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(measure.reshape(1,-1))
    idx_closest = indices[0,0] 
    idx_right = idx_closest + 1 
    idx_left = idx_closest - 1 
    lowest, highest = coordinates[idx_left],  coordinates[idx_right]
    return lowest , highest

# 2.01 ms
%timeit [fun(measure,nbrs, coordinates) for measure in input_data]
```

Comment: Feed in entire data : `distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(input_data)`? In the next step, use flattened indices : `idx_closest = indices.ravel()`.

Comment: @Divakar if you make that an answer, I can mark it as a good one

Comment: I think that's a trivial one. I would encourage you to post your own answer on it. Feel free to use those codes/comments from my earlier comment.

Comment: indeed, I will do that.  Thanks a lot !